Convert STRING_AGG into For XML PATH
I have the following query:
SELECT
    MarisCostNum = c.cost_id,
    SpotDischargePort = dp.portid,
FROM
    cos_middle_cost c WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN 
    voy_voyage v WITH(NOLOCK) ON v.voyage_id = c.owner_id
LEFT JOIN 
    voy_voyage_spot vs WITH(NOLOCK) ON vs.voyage_id= v.voyage_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    cha_contract cha WITH(NOLOCK) ON cha.contract_id = vs.spot_contract_id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         [spot_contract_id], [PortID] = STRING_AGG(cast(port_id AS VARCHAR), ' and ') 
     FROM 
         [cha_discharge_port] WITH(NOLOCK) 
     GROUP BY 
         spot_contract_id) dp ON dp.spot_contract_id = cha.contract_id

I need to amend the final left join into using FOR XML PATH:
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT [spot_contract_id], [PortID] = STRING_AGG(cast(port_id AS VARCHAR), ' and ') 
     FROM [cha_discharge_port] WITH(NOLOCK) 
     GROUP BY spot_contract_id) dp ON dp.spot_contract_id = cha.contract_id

But I am not sure how to do this... Please help

See Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere - it is not recommended to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Given that the grouping column is also the join column, it's probably easiest to do this with an APPLY
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT PortID = STUFF((
        SELECT CONCAT(' and ', cha.port_id)
        FROM cha_discharge_port cha
        WHERE dp.spot_contract_id = cha.contract_id
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(' and '), '')
) cha


The CONCAT adds the separator. Note there is no column name.
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE aggregates as XML with no node name.
.value de-entitizes the XML back to a string.
STUFF strips off the first separator. This is optional if you don't mind a separator at the beginning.

You've picked up some bad habits:

Don't use NOLOCK unless you really, really, really know what you're doing.
Don't use varchar without a length.


Hi @charlieface
Thanks for the details. I tried your code but i keep getting the error prompt:
"Parse error at line: 17, column 3: Incorrect syntax near 'FOR'.
There doesn't seem to be any errors though and i am beginning to wonder whether my SQL is out of date.

Please put your code in a https://dbfiddle.uk so I can check
